# Linux set permission to a folder and all it's sub files or folders

Tags: linux, fedora

i am using fedora and a folder i want to set permission public every one read write

```
chmod -R 755 /directory
chmod owner group world FileName
```

and other's but can't work

**how i can give public permission to every one one of my folder and every thing under it to other users**

thanks

Comment: Try this. It's fine explained:

http://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux

Comment: i went trough all it's example but not work with me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following two commands will ensure your purpose

```
chmod -R 755 /directory
chown -R owner.group /directory
```

This will give read permissions to everyone. You may be facing issue due to wrong ownership. If the file is not very sensitive, you can also use:

```
chown -R nobody.nobody /directory   ( No body means anyone )
```

Comment: 755 is not good enough. need 777.

Answer (score 10):

use command chmod -R 777 yourdirectory

Comment: can not give full permission to other user

Comment: 777 is the correct solution.