# I am able to read a file but unable to write it

Tags: php, apache, file, file-permissions, fedora

I was following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gC8sLGB8SSM&index=77&list=PL442FA2C127377F07 . I am using fedora. I am able to read a file using this code:

```
$fileHandle = fopen('test.txt', 'r') or die('Unable to open test.txt');

echo fread($fileHandle, filesize('test.txt'));
```

But when I change 'r' to 'w', it dies and prints 'Unable to open test.txt'.

To check that I have permissions to read and write to a file, I typed this on terminal, `ls -l /var/www/html`. It showed:

```
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 Hemil apache 131 Jul  6 11:09 index.php
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Hemil Hemil   12 Jul  6 11:09 test.txt
```

I noticed that apache did not have the permission to read and write to a file, I did this: `sudo chown Hemil:apache /var/www/html`. But again when i checked the permissions, it prints the same as above.

**EDIT:** I forgot to add that I am not on a server. I am on localhost.

**EDIT:** On @Nic3500 's recommendation, i add the following:

`ls -al /var`:

```
total 108
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root root  4096 Apr 25 12:09 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root  4096 Jul  7 08:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Apr 25 12:06 account
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 adm
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root root  4096 Jul  5 10:21 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 May 31 10:46 crash
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Apr 25 12:06 db
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Apr 25 12:06 empty
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 ftp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 games
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 gopher
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Jun 15 03:23 kerberos
drwxr-xr-x. 59 root root  4096 Jul  5 11:55 lib
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 local
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    11 Apr 25 12:03 lock -> ../run/lock
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root root  4096 Jul  5 11:52 log
drwx------.  2 root root 16384 Jul  4 22:54 lost+found
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    10 Feb  7 15:11 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 nis
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 opt
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 preserve
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     6 Apr 25 12:03 run -> ../run
drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root  4096 Apr 25 12:06 spool
drwxrwxrwt. 16 root root  4096 Jul  7 18:26 tmp
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root    63 Apr 25 12:09 .updated
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  4096 May  1 14:24 www
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:11 yp
```

`ls -al /var/www`

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root  root   4096 May  1 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root  root   4096 Apr 25 12:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 May  1 14:24 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 Hemil apache 4096 Jul  6 16:17 html
```

`ls -al /var/www/html`

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 Hemil apache 4096 Jul  6 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root  root   4096 May  1 14:24 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 Hemil apache  102 Jul  7 16:55 index.php
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 Hemil apache   12 Jul  6 11:09 test.txt
```

Comment: Try to change file permission by using `chmod`. See this question for additional information: [Linux set permission to a folder and all it's sub files or folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250941/linux-set-permission-to-a-folder-and-all-its-sub-files-or-folders)

Comment: I tried this: `chmod -R 755 /var/www/html` and still the same result @datell

Comment: try `sudo chown -R Hemil:www-data /var/www/html`, assuming `Hemil` is your user

Comment: after that `sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` assign directory write permission to group level

Comment: The first output was `chown: invalid group: ‘Hemil:www-data’`. I replaced 'www-data' with apache, the command is accepted but makes no difference. The second command (with 'find') makes no difference as well. The page still dies @rkj

Comment: did you check the `html` folder permissions ? `ls -all` ?

Comment: This is the output `total 16
drwxrwxr-x. 2 Hemil apache 4096 Jul  6 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root  root   4096 May  1 14:24 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 Hemil apache   83 Jul  6 11:35 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 Hemil apache   12 Jul  6 11:09 test.txt
` @rjk

Comment: How are you running the code? As yourself, or under the web server?

Comment: I am on localhost. I forgot to add it, the question has been edited to include that information @mattdm

Comment: @Hemil Localhost doesn't really answer the question — how is the code being executed? I suspect that writing is being denied by selinux. If that's the case, don't disable selinux but instead configure it to allow what you need. Arbitrary writes to the web root are _exactly what attackers want_.

Comment: I use visual studio code to write the php code and execute it using firefox. I dont know how and what to configure in selinux. @mattdm

Comment: Please add this to the question:  `ls -al /var` then `ls -al /var/www` then `ls -al /var/www/html`.  For selinux, look at how to turn if off completely (google is your friend).  Try it with selinux off.  If it starts to work, then research how to configure it.  Please confirm which user and group your Apache httpd processes run under.

Comment: Added those outputs @Nic3500